# Facebook debugger/URL linter returns “Could not retrieve data from URL”

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

What could be the reason that the Facebook object debugger/URL linter just returns 206 and “Could not retrieve data from URL” for http://test-play.chessclub.com? The scraped URL just shows an empty page.
The site uses a node.js/express server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with node.js/express 2. After upgrading to express 3 the problem vanished.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook can't connect to your server - try the response echo at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Ftest-play.chessclub.com%2F and you'll see they don't get a page back from the server.

Are you filtering on user agent or something? I can see the OG tags fine in my browser.